# pyinstaller doesnt take package

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, pyinstaller

I'm new to python and Pycharm
i did i script using a package named "yagmail" in a virtual environnment,he works perfectly well on pycharm but when i convert it in .exe using pyinstaller and then launching the exe file,it says the module "yagmail"doesnt exist
I already tried using

```
pyi-makespec --paths=/path/to/thisdir \
--paths=/path/to/otherdir myscript.py
```

and changing the spec file
but it doesnt work,does anyone have an idea?
Also here's the github of "yagmail" : https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail#install

Comment: to avoid horrible headache use auto-py-to-exe https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Comment: i tried it but nope still the same error :( ,i think im doing something wrong but idk what,but py-to-exe will definetly help later